# A characterization for initial objects

Tags: category-theory

I want to prove the following:

> Let $c$ be an object in a category $C$. If the
> functor $C(c,-): C\rightarrow Set$ is naturally isomorphic to the constant
> functor $*: C \rightarrow Set$ that sends every object to the singleton set,
> then $c$ is **initial** in $C$.

My attempt: Let's consider a natural isomorphism $\alpha:C(c,-) \cong *$. Then, for every object $x \in C$, and every pair of morphisms $f$,$g:c \rightrightarrows x$, $id_1 \circ \alpha_c= \alpha_x\circ C(c,x)(f)$ and $id_1 \circ \alpha_c= \alpha_x\circ C(c,x)(g)$ (natural square commutativity); because of the components of $\alpha$ are isomorphisms $C(c,x)(f) = C(c,x)(g)$, which means the postcomposition functions $f_*, g_*$ are equal.

I guess that $C(c,-)$ is full, in which case $f=g$ would be immediate; but I couldn't see an argument to prove fullness of $C(c,-)$.

Is $C(c,-)$ full, or there is another argument to prove the desired result?

Comment: I think you are focusing too much on the naturality condition, and not enough of the fact that there is an isomorphism between $C(c,x)$ and a singleton set. For this exercise, you can even forget about the fact that this isomorphism is natural (In fact, if for every $x$, $C(c,x)$ is isomorphic to a singleton set, then this isomorphism is necessarily natural, can you see why?)

Answer (score 5):

If $\eta: C(c , -) \to *$ is a natural isomorphism, then in particular given any object $d \in C$, we have a bijection $\eta_d: C(c , d) \to *(d)$. But latter set has a single element. Hence for every object $d$, there is a unique morphism $c \to d$, so by definition $c$ is initial.

Answer (score 3):

That $\alpha$ is a natural isomorphism means that $\alpha_x\colon C(c,x)\to \operatorname{Map}(*(c),*(x))=\operatorname{Map}(\{*\},\{*\})$ is an isomorphism in **Set**, in particular $C(c,x)$ is a singleton set.